# Trick VHDL Synthesizer to synthesize despite no input signals

Tags: vhdl, programmable-logic

I have a circuit I'm trying to debug and I'd like to eliminate the PLD from the root cause investigation. As such, I'd like to hardwire the outputs of the PLD to a `0` or `1` irregardless of the input combination. I've tried a number of things from using an impossible input combination (in my case, all `Z`), setting the outputs accordingly if the inputs are all don't cares, to simply setting the output to a hard-coded value. While most of these will link and fit in ISPLever, I cannot create a fuse map because I either have too many terms (in the case of all `Z`'s) or I detects no input signal after simplification. I am using a pretty dated PLD (GAL22LV10C-15J), which is probably why it ran out of terms in one of my attempts. The next thing I'm going to try is the following, but I'm sure I'll have the same result:

```
output <= input and (not input);
```

I am doing this so as to ensure the outputs are not floating while I debug the rest of the circuit.

Comment: I'm assuming ISPLever doesn't support the KEEP attribute like Altera and Xilinx's tools do?

You could try the second solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676741/how-to-cheat-synthesis-to-keep-an-unused-signal-without-using-special-compile) if you don't care about the first few clocks.

Comment: \$A\cdot\overline A = 0\$, so that will still get optimised away.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yeah, I know. I was just hoping I'd be able to fool the compiler, but I guess not.

Comment: Well, are there any unused input pins or input pins which are normally a constant level?

Comment: Other than power and ground, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a dummy signal at the architectural level and then assigning to it the hardwired values I wanted. I then attached that dummy signal to the input of my structural entity which I wanted to disable. It worked like a charm. Unfortunately, I remember seeing an answer here suggesting I do exactly that, but it appears it has been removed for some reason. Otherwise I wouldn't be answering my own question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like IPSLever has a syn_preserve attribute that can be set to prevent optimization to constant nets. Here is the example from the *Lattice Synthesis Engine for ispLEVER Classic User Guide*

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity simpledff is
    port (q : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        d : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        clk : in std_logic );
-- Turn on flip-flop preservation for the q output
attribute syn_preserve : boolean;
attribute syn_preserve of q : signal is true;
end simpledff;
architecture behavior of simpledff is
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        -- Notice the continual assignment of "11111111" to q.
        q <= (others => '1');
    end if;
    end process;
end behavior;
```